# Spark - DecisionTree model with wrong features importance

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

I'm running a DecisionTree model and everything looked right except when I ran the feature_importance to check what are the most important features in this model.
The result is wrong because the sum of the feature score is not equal to 1 and I know that the most important feature is smoking_status (a categorical feature).

The output of

`list(zip(assembler.getInputCols(), decisionTreeModel.featureImportances))`

**[('age', 0.1717140615500328),
('bmi', 0.001403579349166339),
('hypertension', 0.0),
('heart_disease', 0.0),
('avg_glucose_level', 0.007257486022061398),
('genderVector', 0.0),
('smokingVector', 0.0)]**

What's wrong with the feature importance result?

Thank you!

Here is the full code:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder

gender_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='gender', outputCol='genderIndexer')
gender_encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol='genderIndexer', outputCol='genderVector')

smoking_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='smoking_status', outputCol='smokingIndexer')
smoking_encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol='smokingIndexer', outputCol='smokingVector')

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['age', 'bmi', 'hypertension', 'heart_disease', 'avg_glucose_level', 'genderVector', 'smokingVector' ], outputCol='features')

classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol='stroke', featuresCol='features')

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[gender_indexer, gender_encoder, smoking_indexer, smoking_encoder, assembler, classifier])

train_data, test_data = strokes.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
predictStrokeModel = pipeline.fit(train_data)

result = predictStrokeModel.transform(test_data)

from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol='stroke', predictionCol='prediction', metricName='accuracy')
accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(result)

decisionTreeModel = predictStrokeModel.stages[5]
decisionTreeModel.depth

decisionTreeModel.toDebugString

list(zip(assembler.getInputCols(), decisionTreeModel.featureImportances))
```

Comment: You have a bunch of vector columns produced by the one-hot encoders. Each value in those vectors becomes a separate feature in the assembled vector. Therefore zipping the input columns with the feature importances gives you the wrong pairing. Check the length of `assembler.getInputCols()` and of `decisionTreeModel.featureImportances` - I bet they don't match.

Comment: @HristoIliev, thanks!
I solved it. The problem was even in transforming the categorical variables using StringIndexer and OneHotEncoder.

Answer (score 0):

This new part of the code solved my issues:

## Define categorical columns

categorical_cols = ['gender', 'smoking_status']

## Define stages for pipeline

indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=c, outputCol="{0}_indexed".format(c)) for c in categorical_cols]
encoders = [OneHotEncoder(inputCol=indexer.getOutputCol(), outputCol="{0}_encoded".format(indexer.getOutputCol())) for indexer in indexers]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['age', 'hypertension', 'heart_disease', 'avg_glucose_level', 'bmi', 'gender_indexed', 'smoking_status_indexed'], outputCol='features')

classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol='stroke', featuresCol='features')

## Define pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + encoders + [assembler, classifier ])

Comment: Are you sure this is really what you want? None of your '_encoded' columns is present in the assembler's input but the '_indexed' columns are, so you are treating the categorical features as ordinal ones.